# Pandas/matplotlib newbie: aggregating time series data with differing indices?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm getting to grips with pandas/matplotlib, and looking to aggregate multiple data series with (marginally) differing indices. For example:

**Series 1**

| seconds_since_start | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0.0 | 35 |
| 0.8 | 41 |
| 1.1 | 48 |

**Series 2**

| seconds_since_start | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0.0 | 31 |
| 0.7 | 37 |
| 1.1 | 41 |

At present, I'm plotting both series as 2 separate line graphs. Ultimately, I'm looking to create a single line that shows, for any given x value, the mean y of both series. The values between specified points can be assumed to be linear.

I assume this is a common task, but the ways I'm trying involve a lot more complexity than I suspect is necessary.

In short: is there a straightforward way in plot the mean for series that have differing index values?

Notes:

- While the only immediate need is graphing, ideally the aggregation would be calculated in pandas, not matplotlib
- The solution will aggregate >100 different series, not just 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to find the union of the series indices and interpolate the values for any missing ones.
Then the series can be concatenated together and the mean value of each index can be computed. the code below assumes the series are inside a list called `series`.

First, get the union of the indices:

```py
from functools import reduce

new_index = reduce(np.union1d, [s.index.values for s in series])
```

In the example case, `new_index` will be `array([0. , 0.7, 0.8, 1.1])`.

Now, [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) the series and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) them together:

```py
df = pd.concat([s.reindex(new_index).rename(f'Value_{i}') for i, s in enumerate(series)], axis=1)
df = df.interpolate('linear')
df['Avg'] = df.mean(axis=1)
```

Result:

```
                     Value_0  Value_1   Avg
seconds_since_start                        
0.0                     35.0     31.0  33.0
0.7                     38.0     37.0  37.5
0.8                     41.0     39.0  40.0
1.1                     48.0     41.0  44.5
```

Comment: Aha! ".interpolate" was the secret sauce I was after, thanks @shaido

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.concat` to aggregate your 100+ series then group by `seconds_since_start` before compute the mean:

```
dfs = [df1, df2]  # all your data here
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0).groupby('seconds_since_start', as_index=False)['Value'].mean()
df.plot(x='seconds_since_start', y='Value', marker='o')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   seconds_since_start  Value
0                  0.0   33.0
1                  0.7   37.0
2                  0.8   41.0
3                  1.1   44.5
```

[image]